# (Python) Monkeypatch __new__ for objects of type int, float, str, list, dict, set, and module in python

Tags: python, monkeypatching, built-in-types

**I want to implicitly extend the int, float, str, list, dict, set, and module classes with custom built substitutions (extensions).**

When I say 'implicitly', what I mean is that when I declare 'a = 1', and object of the type Custom_Int (as an example) is produced, as opposed to a normal integer object.

Now, I understand and respect the reasons not to do this. Firstly- messing with built-ins is like messing with the laws of physics. No good can come from it. That said- I do understand the gravity of what I'm trying to do and what can happen if I do it wrong.

Second- I understand that modifying a base case will effect not just the current run-time but all running python processes. I feel that by overriding the __new__ method of these base classes, such that it returns Custom_Object_Whatever if and ONLY IF certain environmental factors are true, other run times will remain largely unaffected.

So, getting back to the issue at hand- how can I override the __new__ method of these various types?

Pythons forbiddenfruit package seems to be promising. I havn't had a chance to reeeeeeally investigate it though, and if someone who understands it could summarize what it does, that would save me a lot of time.

Beyond that, I've observed something strange.

Every answer to monkeypatching that doesn't eventually circle back to forbiddenfruit or how forbiddenfruit works has to do with modifying what I will refer to as the 'absolute_dictionary' of the class. Because everything in Python is essentially a mapping (or dictionary) of functions/values to names, if you change the name __new__ within the right mapping, you change the nature of the object.

Problem is- every near-success I've had has it that if I call 'str( 'a' ).__new__( *args )' it works fine *{in some cases}*, but the calling of varOne = 'a' does not seem to actually call str.__new__().

My guess- this has something to do with either python's parsing of a program prior to launch, or else the caching of the various classes during/post launch. Or maybe I'm totally off the mark. Either python pre-reads and applies some regex to it's modules prior to launch or else the machine code, when it attempts to ***implicitly*** create an object, it reaches for something other than the class located in moduleObject.builtins[ __classname__ ]

Any ideas?

Comment: `forbiddenfruit` is an overcomplicated and incomplete mess that uses way too much code to get at the "real" dict of a class, yet makes no effort to fix all the other internals it breaks beyond that dict. It's very easy to end up with arbitrary memory corruption when using it, so just don't.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only person who feels this way. To be blatant- forbiddenfruit is a hot sticky mess. That said though it is the nearest I've found to a worrking method of overriding \_\_new\_\_. I'm not trying to accidentally break the plank_constant- I just want explicit control over atomic objects..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, your best option is probably to modify the CPython source code and build your own custom Python build with your extensions baked into the actual built-in types. The result will integrate a lot better with all the low-level mechanisms you don't yet understand, and you'll learn a lot in the process.

---

Right now, you're getting blocked by a lot of factors. Here are the ones that have come to my mind.

The first is that most ways of creating built-in objects don't go through a `__new__` method at all. They go through C-level calls like [`PyLong_FromLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) or [`PyList_New`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_New). These calls are hardwired to use the actual built-in types, allocating memory sized for the real built-in types, fetching the type object by the address of its statically-allocated C struct, and stuff like that. It's basically impossible to change any of this without building your own custom Python.

The second factor is that messing with `__new__` isn't even enough to correctly affect things that theoretically should go through `__new__`, like `int("5")`. Python has reasons for stopping you from setting attributes on built-in classes, and two of those reasons are *slots* and the *type attribute cache*.

[Slots](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html) are a public part of the C API that you'll probably learn about if you try to modify the CPython source code. They're function pointers in the C structs that make up type objects at C level, and most of them correspond to Python-level magic methods. For example, the `__new__` method has a corresponding `tp_new` slot. Most C code accesses slots instead of methods, and there's code to ensure the slots and methods are in sync, but if you bypass Python's protections, that breaks and everything goes to heck.

The [type attribute cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L19) isn't a public part of anything even at C level. It's a cache that saves the results of type object attribute lookups, to make Python go faster. Its memory safety relies on all type object attribute modification going through `type.__setattr__` (and all built-in type object attribute modification getting rejected by `type.__setattr__`), but if you bypass the protection, memory safety goes out the window and arbitrarily weird results can occur.

The third factor is that there's a bunch of caching for immutable objects. The small int cache, the interned string dict, constants getting saved in bytecode objects, compile-time constant folding... there's a lot. Objects aren't going to be created when you expect. (There's also stuff like, say, `zip` saving the last output tuple and reusing it if it sees you didn't keep a reference, for even more ways object creation will mess with your assumptions.)

There's more. Stuff like, what argument would `int.__new__` even take if you tried to use `int.__new__` to evaluate the expression `5`? Stuff like all the low-level code that knows exactly how to work with the types it expects and will get very confused if it gets a `MyCustomTuple` with a completely different memory layout from a real tuple. Screwing with built-ins has a lot of issues.

Incidentally, one of the things you expected to be a problem is mostly not a problem. Screwing with one Python process's built-ins won't affect other Python processes' built-ins... unless those other processes are created by forking the first process, such as with `multiprocessing` in fork mode.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the case. What if, however, I want to be able to distribute my modified python in a frozen capacity (ie py2app and such). I'm just getting started and havn't scoured py2app's code yet, but modifying my python build and then replicating that through py2pp would/will be a pain the ass. You're right- and I'll do it if I have to- but have you any thoughts?

Comment: @LucasYoung: I wouldn't expect a lot of *additional* problems beyond the regular problems of trying to freeze Python. I don't know much about the current state of tools for trying to freeze Python, though.

Comment: I want to thank you for your extremely thorough answer. Too often when I ask a question I'll get pointed randomly to some tutorial or else receive a lazy response. It's wonderful, for once, to be told not just how to solve the problem, but why to do it as such.

So, in the sober light of day, re-reading your answer, I feel like I have two options. The first is to rewrite the C code as you've suggested. The second would be parsing my python code prior to running. Which do you think would be easiest, and more importantly, more portable?

Comment: Secondly, HOW would I modify the base Python code. I honestly have no idea where to start.

Comment: @LucasYoung: Pre-processing your code is fundamentally limited. It can do things like turning a literal `5` into `MyInt(5)`, but it's going to have a much harder problem with things like `map(list, whatever)`, or doing anything to the ints produced by `enumerate(thing)`. It's a fundamentally static approach to a dynamic problem. Also, it'll never be able to do things like, say, make a function's `__defaults__` a `MyTuple` instead of a `tuple`.

Comment: As for modifying the CPython source code, there's a lot to learn. The first step would be to learn C, if you don't know it yet, and that's a pretty big task for a step 1. The next step would be to read about the Python C API - there's a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) and a [reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), and they're both handy.

Comment: Most of the built-in object implementations are under the [`Objects` directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.8.0/Objects) in the source code, with headers under [`Include`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.8.0/Include). The object implementations are the central parts you'd be changing, and possibly the only parts you'd be changing, particularly if you just want to add methods without changing any existing behavior or object memory layouts.